# How to notify after all download completed from Android download manager

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I'm using Android download manager class. I need to write "Download Complete" after all downloads are completed. I have tried something and it's working. But in here it's writing after file by file completed. I need to write only once (After all are completed). I also tried without a cursor. But I failed to achieve.

```
public class DownloadReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


Context context;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    long receivedID = intent.getLongExtra(
             DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1L);
             DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

    DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
    query.setFilterById(receivedID);
    Cursor cur = mgr.query(query);
    int index = cur.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
    if(cur.) {
        String  filePath = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TITLE));
        if(cur.getInt(index) == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL){
            DatabaseHandler dh = new DatabaseHandler(context);
            dh.addDownloadComplete(new DownloadComplete("Download Complete"));
        }
    }
    cur.close();
}}
```

Comment: What do you mean after all downloads are completed? Do you have a set of download ids you want to check if they are complete, or you just wanna check if every download in the DownloadManager (regardless of whether it comes from your app or not) is complete?

Comment: I'm downloading files from a list. In above example it checks one by one and write Download completed one by one. But  what I need is , after downloading all files I need to write download completed once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a check before notifying all downloads are completed. like

```
query.setFilterByStatus(DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED |
      DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING |
      DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING);
    Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(query);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
      return;
    }else {
      query.setFilterById(receivedID);
      //proceed your...
    }
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that there may be downloads (paused, pending or running) that were started by other applications. Besides it does not check if the downloads are FAILED.

Comment: Register receiver <receiver
            android:name=".receiver.DownloadBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver> this work fine. for your confirmation download any files by other app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think would work. Define a function as follows:

```
public boolean areAllDownloadsComplete(int[] downloadIds) {

    DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

    DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();

    for(int i = 0; i < downloadIds.length; i++) {

        query.setFilterById(downloadIds[i]);

        Cursor cur = mgr.query(query);

        if(cur.moveToNext()) {

            if(cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) != DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {

                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

call this function inside the broadcast (at every download complete notification) as follows:

```
if(areAllDownloadsComplete(THE_DOWNLOAD_IDS)) {
    DatabaseHandler dh = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    dh.addDownloadComplete(new DownloadComplete("Download Complete"));
}
```

You can pass the download ids to your broadcast receiver intent as

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putIntArray("download_ids", THE_DOWNLOAD_IDS);
intent.putExtra(bundle);
```