# Downloaded mp3 files can't open in Downloads folder (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an app that downloads mp3 files from a url. The downloading works, and I get a file in the downloads folder. However, when I click on it, it says "Can't open file." When I use getExternalStorageDirectory(), it also isn't retrieving the file or getting any of the information. Is there something wrong with how I'm implementing the download function? Or is there more I have to do with the download manager? I also tried using addCompletedDownload(), but it would just add a "0" file.

```
    private long DownloadData (Uri uri) {

       long downloadReference;

       downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

       // Create request for android download manager
       DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

       //Setting title of request
       request.setTitle("Downloading Song");

       //Setting description of request
       request.setDescription("Downloading Song from URL");

       //Set the local destination for the downloaded file to a path within the application's external files directory
       request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(MainActivity.this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "DownloadSong.mp3");
       //Enqueue download and save into referenceId
       downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

       return downloadReference;
   }
```

Comment: try to open the downloaded file with a text editor.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! I mean that I can't open it on the emulator in the emulator's downloads folder.

Comment: I would look what these files contain. Maybe they are just HTML files? What is the size of them?

Comment: They should be mp3 files. I downloaded the same file on my computer and checked the size. The sizes match on my emulator and my computer (10.80 MB). The file is also an mp3 file on my computer.

Comment: Maybe it is just the problem withhin the os of the emulator. Can you copy the downloaded file to your linux machine and then check the type of it with "file" command?

Answer (score 1):

The code that you had shown to us is absolutely not enough to understand the problem. [Here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Internet/Download) is an example code for downloading using `DownloadManager`.

According to the symptoms described, I think, you haven't finished the download operation or the writing operation correctly. You should check if the download is finished and the file is written and closed. The fact that a file appeared, means that the downloading and writing had started, but not that they finished correctly.

Using DownloadManager terms, it should be `completed`. Look [How to notify after all download completed from Android download manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43514566/how-to-notify-after-all-download-completed-from-android-download-manager/43515166) about that